# Allowing mobile app to access backend API

Tags: android, cordova, laravel

how can I allow only my (ionic framework) cordova-based android application to access my laravel-based api?

I added this to laravel

```
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

But I think this will allow anyone to access my API. How can I prevent that?

Comment: Don't you have some sort of authentication for your API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use authentication through:

1. API key
2. Credentials
3. Classic [HTTP authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

*But some retro-engineering on your Android application would leave some open doors*